# Meteor: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I try to do something I already did a few times, never encountering such error.

I simply want to find all documents that their X field equals Y in my meteor app:

JS: (helper of template)

```
'friendPictures' : function(){
    var currentFriendId = this._id;
    Pictures.find({ownerId: currentFriendId});
    // DO SOMETHING WITH THE PICTURES
}
```

HTML: (inside the template)

```
{{#each friend}}
    ...
    {{friendPictures}} // Calling for the helper
    ...
{{/each}}
```

I keep getting this error when trying to do the "find()", also in Chrome's console:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?71047b64b5196348bdbe5fd5eea9ac97a5a9eb14:528:3)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?71047b64b5196348bdbe5fd5eea9ac97a5a9eb14:530:22
at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?71047b64b5196348bdbe5fd5eea9ac97a5a9eb14:529:5)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?71047b64b5196348bdbe5fd5eea9ac97a5a9eb14:530:22
at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?71047b64b5196348bdbe5fd5eea9ac97a5a9eb14:529:5)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?71047b64b5196348bdbe5fd5eea9ac97a5a9eb14:530:22
at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?71047b64b5196348bdbe5fd5eea9ac97a5a9eb14:529:5)
```

Anyone got into this situation before?

EDIT:

Example of the document:

```
{
     _id: "DCgKA73wNm2mYAhSD",
     base64: "very long string..."
     ownerId: "fRPD87tHkap9hQyB8",
     tags: [
          "nothing",
          "special"
     ]
}
```

Comment: Does your data structure have circular references?

Comment: @Anko Nope, it's plain and simple document

Comment: Hmm. Could you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? I don't know Meteor, but the next step I'd take is to check what's on those lines mentioned in the stack trace, and see if I could figure it out from that context.

Comment: any reproduction repo or meteorpad.com will help

Comment: I'm missing some context here; can you post a bigger chunk of the code?

is this code part of a helper used in an #each?

Comment: I editted the question to include more code.

Comment: @Anko added document example and more code, is that enough?

Comment: How many documents are we talking about here? And do they all have the same structure? The error presented is common to "asyncronous calls" ( which is something meteor "hides away" from you, but is still happening under the covers). I'm betting that the *"Do something with pictures"* part you are presently not sharing is the cause of the problem

Comment: @BlakesSeven you are one hell of a savior!
I didn't know that Meteor works that way but you were right about the different structure thing, I added tags lately and some pictures didn't have them and removing them from the collection solved it.

Comment: Most answers to questions like you presented are usually about "what you are **not** telling people" as opposed to what you are actually telling people when you ask. Try to be clear up-front with all details, then it is easy to find answers.

Comment: @BlakesSeven thanks, I took it as a point for future questions. Can you please describe in high level what was the source of this problem so I could document it as accepted answer for this question? I'm pretty new to Meteor and still learning it's inner structure.

Comment: @Maboo Still really not sure what to place as an answer here that would be useful for others ( the point of this site really, and not just to answer your question ). As mostly depite your "I removed that"(sic) comment, what I said about the *"code you are not showing"* is actually the real cause. Since you show neither the structure variane or the code that was traversing that, then there really is not a definitive answer. "Points" don't  matter to me. "Correctness" does matter, as it helps people learn in the future.

Comment: @BlakesSeven the code I'm not showing wasn't matter for the answer. I didn't show it because I got this error when investigating using the console of Chrome. If anyone else then me will ever have a collection containing documents with slightly different structures he might bump into this error not knowing where to look, because MongoDB is exactly built for such structures. Therefor I do believe it's helpful.

Comment: I wish I could give you more @Anko - your suggestion was exactly what was calling my call stack exception. For anyone else: I was having EJSON issues all over the error trace.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running it with fetch()?

```
Collection.find({pictureId: currentPicId}).fetch();
```

*fetch* turns the found cursor into an array.
But again, without more info this answer might not be relevant.

Comment: Then maybe the issues is with the `{{#each friend}}` loop?

Comment: When I do console.log(currentFriendId) in helper I get the ID, so I'm not sure it's the issue here.